# C++ Save a string from a struct into a text file

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file

In my program, I have a clock timer and I need it to be saved into a char array[10] which is then implemented into my highscore function. Through my program, I already have a formatted time. Example, if the clock's seconds is lower than ten, I have to add a zero. So, 0:02, and if the clock's seconds is greater than ten, it stays normal. Instead of me using two int variables in my struct, how can I just write a string into my text file? For example, lets write a string called string clocksTime = "0:15".  Note it has already been formatted. Here is my code:

```
struct highscore
{
    // *Want* Change these two int values to a string
    int clockMin;
    int clockSec;
}; 
...[Code]…
// Change the two variables to have it instead, data[playerScore].clock = clocksTime
data[playerScore].clockMin = clockData.minutes;
data[playerScore].clockSec = clockData.seconds;
_strdate(data[playerScore].Date);

// Write the variables into the text file
streaming = fopen( "Highscores.dat", "wb" );
fwrite( data, sizeof(data), 1 , streaming);
```

Comment: Why not just save the struct as is? If you have to load the file again, wouldn't it be nice that you could load it into the same struct? Let data be data and presentation be presentation.

Comment: What's wrong with fprintf, or, if you really want it in a string, snprintf? Or C++ iostreams/stringstream?

Comment: It's a lot easier with `std::string` instead of arrays of `char`. Would it be possible for you to use `std::string`?

Comment: @FabioTurati, the only problem is when I use strings I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use `std::string` it's a lot cleaner. Here is a program that does it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void int_time_to_string(const int int_time, string& string_time);

int main() {

    int clockMin = 0;
    int clockSec = 15;

    string clockMinString;
    string clockSecString;

    int_time_to_string(clockMin, clockMinString);
    int_time_to_string(clockSec, clockSecString);

    string clockString = clockMinString + ":" + clockSecString;

    cout << "clock = " << clockString << endl;

    return 0;
}

// Convert a time in int to char*, and pad with a 0 if there's only one digit
void int_time_to_string(const int int_time, string& string_time) {

    if (int_time < 10) {
        // Only one digit, pad with a 0
        string_time = "0" + to_string(int_time);
    } else {
        // Two digits, it's already OK
        string_time = to_string(int_time);
    }
}
```

If, on the other hand, you can't use `std::string`, you have to resort to C strings, that is, arrays of chars. I'm quite rusty about this, but I think we can use `sprintf` for the conversion, and `strcpy`/`strcat` to deal with some of the lower-level operations (like putting '\0' at the end).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void int_time_to_string(const int int_time, char* string_time);

int main() {

    int clockMin = 0;
    int clockSec = 15;

    char clockMinString[3] = ""; // 2 digits + null character
    char clockSecString[3] = ""; // 2 digits + null character

    int_time_to_string(clockMin, clockMinString);
    int_time_to_string(clockSec, clockSecString);

    char clockString[6]; // 2 digits, colon, 2 more digits, null character
    strcpy(clockString, clockMinString);
    strcat(clockString, ":");
    strcat(clockString, clockSecString);

    cout << "clock = " << clockString << endl;

    return 0;
}

// Convert a time in int to char*, and pad with a 0 if there's only one digit
void int_time_to_string(const int int_time, char* string_time) {

    if (int_time < 10) {
        // Only one digit, pad with a 0
        strcpy(string_time, "0") ;
        char temp[2]; // 1 digit + null character
        sprintf(temp, "%d", int_time);
        strcat(string_time, temp);
    } else {
        // Two digits, it's already OK
        sprintf(string_time, "%d", int_time);
    }
}
```

In both cases you just have to take `clockString`.